# jquery finding the first P

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
$(content).filter("p:first").text();
```

**where content =**

```
<div>
<div>
<div>
<p>adsdas</p>
<p>dsa</p>
<p>dsa</p>
<p>dsa</p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>asdadsadsads</p>
</div><p><br></p><p><br></p><p>asd</p><p><br></p><p><br></p></div>
```

What I want to happen is to find the first PARAGRAPH tag, whether it be at the top or down a child level or more of a div. How can I tell jQuery to find the first

tags all the way down until the first match?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get any level decendant, like this

```
$(content).find("p:first").text();
```

If it may be the top level, it's not as clear, you need to do [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)...but the results are in order, so still take the first, like this:

```
$(content).find("p").andSelf().filter("p:first").first().text();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. One simple way is like so:

```
$("p", content).first().text();
```

I'm assuming content is a variable containing the html. I created an example on jsFiddle... [Have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/Zevan/FQL2L/1/)

Comment: This won't find a `<p>` at the root level, since this translates to: `$(content).find("p").first().text();`...it just takes more steps to get there :)