# Need Experts help How to select only the first paragraph in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need help selecting the first part. Hello my name is joe. and then I need to hide the other part.

```
<p>
  <b>NAME</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  "hello my name is joe"
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>AGE</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  "My age is 22"
  <br>
</p>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML in your question?

Comment: im not sure how too

Comment: it starts with a paragraph tag

Comment: Were you done writing your question when you pressed the submit button? Its not clear what you want to know.

Comment: There is only one paragraph there?

Comment: @JosephLezcano I just edited your question to show the code formatting.  You can do this by selecting your code examples and using the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: It's just one paragraph in that question... $('p') selects all paragraphs that it finds.. $('p')[0] or $(‘p‘).first selects the first one of all the paragraphs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery finding the first P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305931/jquery-finding-the-first-p)

Comment: so $('p').first should grab me what?

Comment: Structure the html into containers with common classes so you can hide specific containers. Using multiple `<br>` for layout is definitely not the way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have textnodes you would need to use [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) on your `p` and then you can loop through and remove any node on or after the second `b` tag

```js
var counter = 0;
var contents = $('p').contents().each(function() { // loop through all nodes in the p
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.is('b')) { // count the b tags
    counter++;
  } 
  
  if (counter >= 2) { // remove anything on or after the second b
    $this.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <b>NAME</b>
  <br>
  <br> "hello my name is joe"
  <br>
  <br>
  <b>AGE</b>
  <br>
  <br> "My age is 22"
  <br>
</p>
```

Comment: What if OP wants to display it again?

Comment: Then they should edit their question to say show and hide - it currently only says hide.  But if that were the case, I would append it to a newly created span inside the p (instead of removing it) that I can hide and show to my hearts content